# Get a specific IndexPath for a value to reloadRow

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

Right now, I am using this code to update the online status of a user. Every time, the online status changes, my whole TableView gets reloaded:

```
    // Get and update the actual online stats for the users
    UserApi.shared.getUserOnlineStatus { (onlineStatus) in
        if let user = self.users.first(where: {$0.uid == onlineStatus.keys.first}) {
            let values = onlineStatus.values.first as? Array<Any>
            let onlineStatus = values?[0]
            user.onlineStatus = onlineStatus as? Bool
            }
        self.tableViewUsers.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

I am not an expert, but I have the feeling I should only reload the affected row.

How can I get the specific IndexPath for

**self.users.first(where: {$0.uid == onlineStatus.keys.first})**

, so I can just reload the row?

Edit, working Code:

```
    // Get and update the actual online stats for the users
    UserApi.shared.getUserOnlineStatus { (onlineStatus) in

        if let user = self.users.first(where: {$0.uid == onlineStatus.keys.first}) {
            let values = onlineStatus.values.first as? Array<Any>
            let onlineStatus = values?[0]
            user.onlineStatus = onlineStatus as? Bool
            }

        if let index = self.users.firstIndex(where: {$0.uid == onlineStatus.keys.first}) {
            self.tableViewUsers.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
        UserApi.shared.getUserOnlineStatus { (onlineStatus) in
            if let user = self.users.first(where: {$0.uid == onlineStatus.keys.first}) {
                let values = onlineStatus.values.first as? Array<Any>
                let onlineStatus = values?[0]
                user.onlineStatus = onlineStatus as? Bool

                if let index = self.users.firstIndex(of: user) {
                    self.tableViewUsers.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                }
            }
        }
```

First you need to get the index of the modified user in your users list and then reload the row at that index using the UITableView function [`[reloadRows(at:with:)]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows)

Comment: I think I understand what you said, but got this error. Trying to get the rest working. Thanks. "Argument type 'UserModel' does not conform to expected type 'Equatable'"

Comment: @ProjektWeinheim you can use enumerated() function of swift array here to get things done. Give it a shot. If you struggle to get this, I can help. Cheers.

Comment: Thx Dude! Really appreciate it. I solved it with:             if let index = self.users.firstIndex(where: {$0.uid == onlineStatus.keys.first}) {
                self.tableViewUsers.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
            }